# Does Postal Mail Server work on port 2525?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm want to install an open-source mail server called **Postal Mail Server** on Google Cloud VM instances.
As I know Postal works on port 25 and Google cloud has port 25 blocked on each VM.
Does postal work on port 2525 so I can use it?

Comment: This link shows how to change the port number in `/opt/postal/config/postal.yml` https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-setup-postal-mail-server-on-ubuntu-18-04_595921

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question - yes - it does work on 2525 but sue to security reasons GCP [blocks outgoing SMTP traffic from VM instances on port 25](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic) - you can use other ports though, and that's what official documentation has to say about [sending out emails from your VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail):

> By default, Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports
> but port 25, which is blocked because of the risk of abuse. All other
> ports are open, including ports 587 and 465.

Bottom line is - you have to use alternative [mail service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#choosing_an_email_service_to_use) and you have several choices such as Sendgrid, Mailgun or Mailjet.

When you decide on a service you want to use and a port - you have to [create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#email_custom_port) to allow smtp outgoing traffic.